# How to implement a java method to set a user name

Tags: java, methods

I'd like to implement a method to set / change a name. E.g.: preset name is = "Ben". With a method it should be possible to change the name to = "Charly". My approach so far:

```
public void setName (String name)
{
name = "";
}
```

When I call the method I can type in the name but my JDK (blueJ) does not keep the name. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Assuming your class has a `name` field, you should do `this.name = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the code to the following (assuming you have a reference variable called `name` in your class):

```
public void setName (String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

This is called Variable Shadowing in Java. E.g. when there are two variables (i.e. local and instance) with the same name, local varialble takes precedence over instance variable and hence, statements like:

```
name = "";
```

assign the values to local variable `name` rather than instance variable. To assign value to instance variable, we can use `this` keyword (to access and modify the value).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your method, you should change the name variable of you class object. Here is an exmaple where you have user class and you want to update its name:

```
public class user {
String name;
public user(){
    name = "";
}

public void setName(String newName){
    name = newName;
}
```

}